# CTE multiplication resulting in multiple result rows

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

EDIT - The problem was that the same item showed up multiple times in different spots in the BOM which then produced a result row for every instance instead of just one. This has been resolved. Thanks

I have the following code

```
WITH tBomCTE (ParentItem, ChildItem, WorkCentre, Operation, Quantity, ActualQuantity, ParentUnitWeight, ParentWeightUnitOfMeasure, ChildUnitWeight, ChildWeightUnitOfMeasure, BomLevel, MaterialClass, ParentItemSource) AS
(
    SELECT
        id.parentitem, id.ChildItem, id.WorkCentre, id.Operation, 
        id.Quantity, id.Quantity, id.ParentUnitWeight, 
        id.ParentWeightUnitOfMeasure, id.ChildUnitWeight, 
        id.ChildWeightUnitOfMeasure, 
        0 as BomLevel, id.MaterialClassCode, ParentItemSource
    FROM
        @tItemDenomalized id
    WHERE
        id.parentitem = '10054471'

    UNION ALL

    SELECT
        id.parentitem, id.ChildItem, id.WorkCentre, id.Operation, 
        id.Quantity, CAST((id.Quantity * b.ActualQuantity) AS DECIMAL(19,8)), id.ParentUnitWeight, 
        id.ParentWeightUnitOfMeasure, id.ChildUnitWeight, 
        id.ChildWeightUnitOfMeasure, 
        BomLevel + 1, 
        id.MaterialClassCode, id.ParentItemSource
    FROM
        tBomCTE b
    JOIN
        @tItemDenomalized id ON b.ChildItem = id.parentitem
)
SELECT DISTINCT
    'T1', ParentItem, ChildItem, WorkCentre, Operation, Quantity,  
    ActualQuantity, 
    COALESCE(ParentUnitWeight, 0), ParentWeightUnitOfMeasure, 
    COALESCE(ChildUnitWeight, 0), ChildWeightUnitOfMeasure, BomLevel, 
    MaterialClass, ParentItemSource
FROM 
    tBomCTE
```

The problem is that this code is producing multiple result rows. I have isolated it down to the `cast((id.Quantity * b.ActualQuantity) as decimal(19,8))`line.

Basically i am trying to build a Bill Of Materials (BOM) and we had a problem with the quantity not being added up appropriately. For example if we needed 2 of the parent item, the child item quantity only reflected what we needed for 1. Which was messing up costs.

So that line was added. It has never caused a problem but we just ran a test and now it is causing issues.

Specifically. I have a parent item, then child 1, then child 2. When I run this code i get 3 results for child 2 that all have the same path from the parent. So that doesn't make sense. And then the quantities are 22, 44, 66 for the 3 child 2 items respectively.

If i had to guess it looks like whats happening is that the quantity does get multiplied to the parent. Which then turns into 22. Then i gets multiplied by the next parent and instead of multiplying, it is creating a new row entirely.

Right now my solution is to update the quantities with code and then to delete all duplicate rows to get rid of the extra rows. But this is bad practice.

Why is it producing multiple rows instead of multiplying the parent to the current item?

Edit.

Here is my entire stored procedure that is causing the problem:

```
IF EXISTS (SELECT * 
       FROM   sysobjects 
       WHERE  id = object_id(N'[dbo].[spSAL_BomRecursive]') 
              AND OBJECTPROPERTY(id, N'IsProcedure') = 1 )
BEGIN
    DROP PROCEDURE [dbo].[spSAL_BomRecursive];
END
GO

CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[spSAL_BomRecursive]
(
     @SessionId             varchar(50)
    ,@Item                  [dbo].[ItemType] = NULL
    ,@DebugLevel            BIT = 0
    ,@CurrentOrStandardBOM  nvarchar(1) = 'C'
)
AS
BEGIN

SET NOCOUNT ON;

--declare @Item         varchar(30);
--set @item = '10029554';

Declare @tItemDenomalized TABLE (ParentItem nvarchar(30), 
                                 ChildItem nvarchar(30), 
                                 WorkCentre nvarchar(30) ,
                                 Operation nvarchar(30),  
                                 Quantity decimal(19,8), 
                                 ParentUnitWeight decimal(18,9),
                                 ParentWeightUnitOfMeasure nvarchar(3), 
                                 ChildUnitWeight decimal(18,9), 
                                 ChildWeightUnitOfMeasure nvarchar(3), 
                                 MaterialClassCode nvarchar(30),
                                 ParentItemSource nvarchar(30));

Declare @CurrentOrStandardSuffix int
Set @CurrentOrStandardSuffix = Case when @CurrentOrStandardBOM = 'C' then 0 else 1 end

-- populate a table with all of the items, merging data to make the recursive SQL easier 
Insert into @tItemDenomalized
        select distinct i.item,  coalesce(jm.item, ''), jr.wc, jr.oper_num, coalesce(jm.matl_qty, 0) as qty ,i.unit_weight as ParentUnitWeight, i.weight_units as ParentWeightUnitOfMeasure, i2.unit_weight as ChildUnitWeight, i2.weight_units as ChildWeightUnitOfMeasure, i.Uf_SalMaterialClassCode as MaterialClass, i.p_m_t_code
        from item_mst i
          left join jobroute_mst jr on i.job = jr.job and jr.suffix = @CurrentOrStandardSuffix
          left join jobmatl_mst jm on jr.job = jm.job and jr.oper_num = jm.oper_num and jr.suffix = jm.suffix
          left join item_mst i2 on coalesce(jm.item, '') = i2.item;

WITH tBomCTE ( ParentItem, ChildItem, WorkCentre, Operation, Quantity, ActualQuantity, ParentUnitWeight, ParentWeightUnitOfMeasure, ChildUnitWeight, ChildWeightUnitOfMeasure, BomLevel, MaterialClass, ParentItemSource )
    AS
    (
        select id.parentitem, id.ChildItem, id.WorkCentre, id.Operation, id.Quantity, id.Quantity, id.ParentUnitWeight, id.ParentWeightUnitOfMeasure, id.ChildUnitWeight, id.ChildWeightUnitOfMeasure, 0 as BomLevel, id.MaterialClassCode, ParentItemSource
        from @tItemDenomalized id
          where id.parentitem = @item

    UNION ALL

        select id.parentitem, id.ChildItem, id.WorkCentre, id.Operation, id.Quantity, cast((id.Quantity * b.ActualQuantity) as decimal(19,8)) , id.ParentUnitWeight, id.ParentWeightUnitOfMeasure, id.ChildUnitWeight, id.ChildWeightUnitOfMeasure, BomLevel+1, id.MaterialClassCode, id.ParentItemSource
        from tBomCTE b
          join @tItemDenomalized id on b.ChildItem = id.parentitem
    )


insert into tSAL_Bom
           ([SessionId],[ParentItem],[ChildItem],[WorkCentre],[Operation],[Quantity],[ActualQuantity],[ParentUnitWeight],[ParentWeightUnitOfMeasure],[ChildUnitWeight],[ChildWeightUnitOfMeasure],[BomLevel],[MaterialClassCode],[ParentItemSource])
    SELECT distinct @SessionId, ParentItem, ChildItem, WorkCentre, Operation, Quantity, ActualQuantity, coalesce(ParentUnitWeight, 0), ParentWeightUnitOfMeasure, coalesce(ChildUnitWeight, 0), ChildWeightUnitOfMeasure, BomLevel, MaterialClass, ParentItemSource
    FROM tBomCTE

-- cleanup the table from yesterday
delete from tSAL_Bom
 where CreatedOn < Getdate()-1

RETURN 0;

END
GO
```

The problematic data rows are the following

```
SortingOrder    DepthLevel  ItemOrWorkCenterNumber  BaseQuantity    Quantity

[10054471]          0             10054471               1             1

[10054471][1605][10008773]  1   10008773    1   2

[10054471][1605][10008773][1100][10024306]  2   10024306    2   4

[10054471][1605][10008773][1100][10024306][1005][10030273]  3   10030273    11  22

[10054471][1605][10008773][1100][10024306][1005][10030273]  3   10030273    11  44

[10054471][1605][10008773][1100][10024306][1005][10030273]  3   10030273    11  66
```

So as you can hopefully see. There should be 1 row that looks like this

```
[10054471][1605][10008773][1100][10024306][1005][10030273]  3   10030273    11  88
```

Because the main parent requires 1. The first child requires 2. So our multiplier is 2. Our next parent requires 2 normally but with the multiplier requires 4 which makes our multiplier now 8. This line is correct. Then the next line should be the base quantity of 11 times the multiplier of 8. So 88. But instead i am getting a row that is multiplied by 2, and 4 and 6.

Comment: How about some table definitions and sample data? Here is a great place to start. http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/

Comment: Your base case has the column id.Quantity twice.  that doesn't look right.  Also I don't get (from the business angle) how you can mulitply two quantities together: `id.Quantity * b.ActualQuantity`.  e.g. If I multiply 2 apples by 2 apples, what do I get? 4 apples-squared?

Comment: I added in a lot more information. Please let me know if there is anything else @SeanLange

Comment: @user1443098. It has the quantity twice because the base case has no parent items to determine any additional quantities. So we just take the base value. 

And to answer your other question. If want an apple, and every apple has 20 seeds and 1 apple core. then if I want 3 apples. I need to have 20*3 seeds and 1*3 apple cores. So the idea is to multiply the child quantity by that of the parent to figure out how much of the child we actually need.

Comment: I appreciate the effort but that isn't quite it. I can't run this because I don't have all those tables you use for your insert inside that procedure. And if that sample data is supposed to be the results of that select I can't decipher what is what in there.

Comment: Yeah the problem is that it is way too much data to post here. 

Basically the temp table stores all parent and child items. I have checked and for the problem parent "10024306" there is only one record with "10030273" and that is for 11 of the child. So that checks out. 

I am hoping the fact that I isolated the problem to the multiplication line would help. But i guess it doesn't

Comment: @StephanusDJ you should use an alias for one of those to ensure that the reference is distinct. I am quite surprised that sql server does not complain about ambiguity

Comment: You don't need to post thousands of lines of data, just enough data to represent the problem you are facing.

Comment: Thoughts: `coalesce(jm.matl_qty, 0)` is suspicious. Just off the top of my head, a default quantity of `1` would seem more likely. It is often enlightening to simply `select * from tBOMcte` and see what the recursion is actually doing. As for providing data and code, a minimal example in [SQL Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/) would make it much easier for us to help you.

Comment: I HIGHLY recommend to wait until the OP provide DDL+DML in these type of questions, for 3 main reasons: `(1)` a person that come to ask a question should learn how to ask the question for future cases (provide information to reproduce the issue: "table definitions and sample data" or "DDL+DML"). `(2)` it will prevent what I call "a guessing game" where each one guess what is the the real scenario. `(3)` The OP should do his part to show some effort before he get the privilege to ask people to spend their free time (do as much as he can so we will do as little as we can in order to help him).

Answer (score 1):

This isn't really an answer to your question, but an attempt to break down the massive amount of logic into something reproducible.

I wrote a very quick, self-encapsulated query that "sort of" does what I think you are trying to do.  Maybe you could do something similar to explain what the differences between my logic and your logic are?

```
WITH Base AS (
    SELECT 1 AS id, NULL AS parent, 1 AS multiplier
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 2 AS id, 1 AS parent, 2 AS multiplier
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 3 AS id, 2 AS parent, 4 AS multiplier),
Recurs AS (
    SELECT
        id,
        1 AS depth,
        multiplier
    FROM
        Base
    WHERE
        id = 1
    UNION ALL
    SELECT
        b.id,
        depth + 1 AS depth,
        b.multiplier * r.multiplier AS multiplier
    FROM
        Base b
        INNER JOIN Recurs r ON r.id = b.parent),
SecondRecurs AS (
    SELECT
        id,
        depth,
        multiplier
    FROM
        Recurs
    UNION ALL
    SELECT
        p.parent,
        s.depth,
        s.multiplier
    FROM
        SecondRecurs s
        INNER JOIN Base b ON b.id = s.id
        INNER JOIN Base p ON p.id = b.parent),
Ordered AS (
    SELECT
        *,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY depth DESC, id) AS order_id
    FROM
        SecondRecurs)
SELECT
    id,
    depth,
    multiplier
FROM
    Ordered
WHERE
    order_id = 1;
```

So how does this work?

First I make some test data:

```
id  parent  multiplier
1   NULL    1
2   1   2
3   2   4
```

Then I use a recursive CTE to get the depth/ multiplier, using similar logic to your example:

```
id  depth   multiplier
1   1   1
2   2   2
3   3   8
```

But I deliberately let this run without worrying about rolling up children into parents, so now I have a second stage to get this into some sort of order:

```
id  depth   multiplier  order_id
1   3   8   1
3   3   8   2
NULL    2   2   3
2   2   2   4
1   1   1   5
```

Finally I can pick out the row I want, ignoring the "partial" results that you seem to be getting in your query?

```
id  depth   multiplier
1   3   8
```

Does this help at all?